# Show that the equation $x^2+y^2-2ax-14y+40=0$ represents a circle for every $a$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, circles, conic-sections

> Show that the following equation represents a circle for every $a$:$$x^2+y^2-2ax-14y+40=0 .$$

My answer is:
\begin{align*}
(x-a)^2 - a^2 + (y-7)^2 -49+40 & =0\\
(x-a)^2+(y-7)^2 & =a^2+9\\
\implies \quad a^2+9 & >0\\
a^2 & > -9
\end{align*}

For every $ a \in   \mathbb{R}$, $a^2 > -9$, so the equation represents a circle for every $a$.

Is this correct? And especially, my conclusion, how would that be written correctly, because I know I've probably done something wrong?

Comment: It seems all correct to me.

Comment: Even the notation of my conclusion?

Comment: I've slightly edited the conclusion. My advice is "When writing a formula, be able to translate it in your language": symbols are just a useful shortcut, they don't change the meaning of what you're saying.

Comment: It would be better if you start from your equation and complete the squares to obtain the other equation. It is just a matter of formality. The part about $a^2$ is trivially true. That will provide the radius of the circle.

Comment: @AndreaOrta thank you